# How to Customize Lock Screen Shortcuts on the OnePlus 3 and OnePlus 3T

Tags: lock-screens, camera, home-screen-shortcuts, oneplus-3, oxygenos

I have installed a new camera app that I'd like to use by default. I set it as the default app in the settings, but that didn't make it the target app for the lock screen shortcut or the O gesture.

[image: How to customize the camera app that opens with this shortcut?]

Answer (score 0):

The most simple method - and I've tried this on my own OnePlus 3 running OxygenOS Open Beta 21 - is to simply disable the stock camera app - known as "OnePlus Camera" on OnePlus devices.

To disable it, go to `Settings > Apps > OnePlus Camera > Disable`

That should do the trick.

Comment: I tried that but didn't quite do the trick.  It removed the shortcut all together from the lock screen!